# jQuery title expand/collapse (like on youtube)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube

So basically I have a div (or span) that I want to trim to (let's say) 120 words and add three dots at the end, then when some one clicks that div (or span) it expands to the rest of the content, but also when someone clicks it again it does opposite.

Same principle is with YouTUbe title; if it's too long youtube adds three dots and you can click to expand, then click to collapse, then click to expand ...

Here's where I've come to with my fiddle and than stuck right in there.

```
<span class="expanding">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span>
```

JS:

```
var ttext = $('.expanding').text();
$('.expanding').text($('.expanding').text().substr(0, 120)).append('...');
$('body').on('click', '.expanding', function () {
    $(this).text(ttext);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Casp3r/6gaSN/

Comment: So far I have it to expand, but NOT TO collapse on second, reexpand on third click etc.

Comment: if I got it correctly, you want to expand on 1st click and then collapse it on the second ? and then continue the same! ?

Comment: Exactly my good fellow Ajey. I've put in an example of such thing (title on youtube video's). I've managed it to get it working to expand but stuck after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out..

```
var ttext = $('.expanding').text();
$('.expanding').text($('.expanding').text().substr(0, 120)).append('...');
var stext = $('.expanding').text();
$('body').on('click', '.expanding', function () {

   if($(this).text() == ttext){
      $(this).text(stext);
   }else{
      $(this).text(ttext);
   }
```

});

Comment: Nice, exactly what I needed, you Sir saved my sanity.

Comment: My Pleasure.. If my answer is working for you can you please tick my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ajey/6RwfB/)

basically I make use of an `variable` to store the state of the previous click and accordingly  switch between them.

Answer (score 0):

There is this little plugin by Karl Swedberg: https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-expander - Works like a charm! :)